# error reoccurring in code that uses dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

this is my code:

```r
lcdf %>%
  group_by(purpose) %>%
  summarise(
    nLoans=n(),
    defaults=sum(loan_status=="Charged Off"),
    avgInterest= mean(int_rate),
    avgLoanAMt=mean(loan_amnt)
  )
```

I get this error:

```r
Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

What do I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show `dput(lcdf)`. Your syntax seems correct?  Try this on a fresh R session with only `library(dplyr)` loaded

Comment: Restart R, then either (1) don't load `plyr`, or (2) load `dplyr` *second*. To confirm, type in just `summarise`, and I'm going to guess that the output ends with `<environment: namespace:plyr>` (which does *not* know what to do with `n()`. It should end with `<environment: namespace:dplyr>`.